# return data inside function but not view on html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router','ngTasty']);
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: function($scope, $http, $location) {
                $scope.getData = function(params) {
                    var dataUrl = 'main/home/?';
                    $scope.urlApiTwo = dataUrl + params;
                    return mydata($scope.urlApiTwo, $http);
                };
            }
        });
}]);

function mydata(urxx, $http) {
    return $http.get(urxx).then(function(response) {
        return {
            'rows': response.data.rows,
            'header': response.data.header,
            'pagination': response.data.pagination,
            'abc': response.data.abc
        };
    });
}
```

I need to access "abc" data in `home.html`. but this is not view.

console log data:

> {"header":[{"name":"Id"},{"name":"Subject"},{"name":"Status"}],"rows":[{"ids":"1","subject":"Hindi","status":"1"},{"ids":"2","subject":"English","status":"1"},{"ids":"3","subject":"Mathematics","status":"1"},{"ids":"4","subject":"Science","status":"1"},{"ids":"5","subject":"Social Science","status":"1"}],"pagination":{"count":"5","page":1,"pages":16,"size":80},"abc":[{"value":"home"}]}

Comment: Please clarify what you need specifically. Looks like `abc` is addressable from `response.data.pagination.abc`?

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve data with `$scope.getData` use returned promise `then` method

```
$scope.getData(params).then(function(data) {
    $scope.abc = data.abs;
});
```